# Rails - Jbuilder and use of partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I have a template that takes an array of objects, and for each object it needs to render a partial template. The result comes back as empty objects. Any idea what's wrong in the code??

Controller

```
def index
   render text: render_to_string(template: 'users.json.jbuilder', locals: {:@uses : users}
end
```

users.json.jbuilder

```
json.array! @users do |user|
     json.partial! 'user.json.jbuilder', { user: user}
end
```

user.json.jbuilder

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
   json.id user.id
   json.username user.user_name
end
```

Result

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.json.jbuilder` means that `Jbuilder.encode do |json|` is already summoned.

So, your `user.json.jbuilder` file would become functional as follows:

```
json.id user.id
json.username user.user_name
```

That's it... End of story :)